# Can anyone explain the order in which string.Join joins?

Tags: c#, .net

Here's input file content:

```
Time,MW
01/01/2014 1:00:00 AM,2617
01/01/2014 2:00:00 AM,2544
01/01/2014 3:00:00 AM,2458
01/01/2014 4:00:00 AM,2395
01/01/2014 5:00:00 AM,2349
01/01/2014 6:00:00 AM,2375
01/01/2014 7:00:00 AM,2359
01/01/2014 8:00:00 AM,2418
...
```

And here's the desired output: where Weekday = 1, Weekend = 0, Winter = 1, Mid = 2, Summer = 3

```
Time,MW,Hour,Weekday,Season
01/01/2014 1:00:00 AM,2617,1,1,1
01/01/2014 2:00:00 AM,2544,2,1,1
01/01/2014 3:00:00 AM,2458,3,1,1
01/01/2014 4:00:00 AM,2395,4,1,1
01/01/2014 5:00:00 AM,2349,5,1,1
01/01/2014 6:00:00 AM,2375,6,1,1
01/01/2014 7:00:00 AM,2359,7,1,1
01/01/2014 8:00:00 AM,2418,8,1,1
...
```

Here's the code:

```
var inLines = File.ReadAllText(IN_CSV).Split('\n');
var outLines = new List<string>();
outLines.Add(OUT_CSV_HEADER);
foreach (var line in inLines)
{
    if (line.Contains("Time,MW")) continue;
    List<string> ocl = BuildOutCsvLine(line);
    var oclFinal = "";
    ocl.ForEach(o => {
        System.Console.WriteLine(o);
        oclFinal = string.Join(",", oclFinal, o);
    });
    System.Console.WriteLine(oclFinal);
    break;
    //outLines.Add(ocl);
}
private static List<string> BuildOutCsvLine(string inCsvLine) {
    var inCsvData = inCsvLine.Split(',');
    var timestamp = DateTime.ParseExact(inCsvData[0], "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    var season = seasons.GetSeason(timestamp);
    var tod = timestamp.Hour.ToString();
    var wd = ((int)timestamp.GetWeekDayType()).ToString();
    var ssn = ((int)season.Id).ToString();

    return new List<string> { inCsvLine, tod, wd, ssn };
}
```

Here's the output:

```
01/01/2014 1:00:00 AM,2617
1
1
1
,1,1,1/2014 1:00:00 AM,2617
```

I also tried `StringBuilder` to append all element and create CSV string, but produces same result.

Is there any format issue (e.g. `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, etc.. that I have to use)? I tried `InvariantCulture`, but same result.

I doubt on .NET framefwork, do I need to apply some patch?

Comment: You should mention example input and expected output.

Comment: What is the problem in this output and what result did you expect

Comment: If you look at at the output I posted, the first four lines are the order in which the List<string> has items and I want the string.Join to join them in that order. but if you look at the 5th line, the output is scrambled. Did it help?

Comment: Can you post several lines of that o returns? I mean in the ocl.ForEach(o=> expression?

Comment: @Vikrant You should also post the input file...

Comment: The ocl `List` has only 4 elements, as they are in the first 4 lines of the output. The input file has 8759 rows and two columns as Time,MW. What I do is extract Hour, weekday/weekend info and season from the time and create another CSV file with Time,MW,Hour,Weekday,Season. For this, I use `string.Join` to combine that `List` into a CSV row.

Comment: I need to see only this:     ocl.ForEach(o => {
        System.Console.WriteLine(o);} withought any string joins and other format. Can you post the result of that output?

Comment: Updated the question with input and desired output file content.

Comment: @user1551066: okay, done, here's the output:
    `01/01/2014 1:00:00 AM,2617` <br>
    `1` <br>
    `1` <br>
    `1` <br>
(<br> I can't add a new line, so think it is there with <br>)

Comment: Nice. So as I understood the o returns this line '01/01/2014 1:00:00 AM,2617', right? But where you get this - 1,1,1?

Comment: @user1551066: added the function for your reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, though I can't completely test it because you didn't provide the whole code. Particularly, seasons is undefined for me.

Sorry, Updated. Misplaced code.

```
var inLines = File.ReadAllText(IN_CSV).Split('\n');
var outLines = new List<string>();
outLines.Add(OUT_CSV_HEADER);
foreach (var line in inLines)
{
    if (line.Contains("Time,MW")) continue;
    List<string> ocl = BuildOutCsvLine(line);
    var oclFinal = "";
    ocl.ForEach(o => {
        oclFinal = string.Join(",", oclFinal, o);
    });
    System.Console.WriteLine(oclFinal);
}
    private static List<string> BuildOutCsvLine(string inCsvLine)
    {
        var clearR = inCsvLine.Replace("\r", "");
        var clearN = clearR.Replace("\n", "");
        var inCsvData = clearN.Split(',');
        var timestamp = DateTime.ParseExact(inCsvData[0], "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var season = seasons.GetSeason(timestamp);
        var tod = timestamp.Hour.ToString();
        var wd = ((int)timestamp.GetWeekDayType()).ToString();
        var ssn = ((int)season.Id).ToString();

        return new List<string> { clearN, tod, wd, ssn };
    }
```

Comment: It worked! You are a great help! In future, I have to keep the line termination in mind while manipulating `string` read from a file!!! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help). But I wouldn't even create a List collection for this purpose. I would return a string (comma separated) from your BuildOutCsvLine. And in the foreach loop I would use StringBuilder to collect all the strings and separate them by '\n'.

Comment: I used `List` for some debugging. But yes, you are right and have already done the same !

Comment: And you probably don't need this line  var clearN = clearR.Replace("\n", ""); because you split the text by this character.

Comment: You are right, somehow, your suggestion worked, so would test this out first thing getting back to that code work! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The order of `string.Join()` is the same as the order of the elements you supply. .Net does not change the order internally.

Comment: Yes, that's what's expected, but if you look at the output I posted, `string.Join` is scrambling the order!

Comment: You can have look at the source code of string.Join by yourself - .NET does not scramble it. There is also no culture specific dependency in there.
I also tried your original code and got the correct order - I was not able to produce the wrong output.

Comment: Yeah, there was a problem around not taking care of the line termination (\n and \r), pointed out by @user1551066, strange enough that these line termination issue made me ask this question!

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying, concatenation ocl list element in oclFinal

```
List<string> ocl = BuildOutCsvLine(line);
var oclFinal = "";
ocl.ForEach(o => {
    System.Console.WriteLine(o);
    oclFinal = string.Join(",", oclFinal, o);
});
```

You can do this by

```
List<string> ocl = BuildOutCsvLine(line);
var oclFinal = "";
oclFinal=string.Join(",",ocl);
```

Comment: I tried this but the output of `string.Join` has the order which is not same as the supplied `List<string>`'s order. This is the reason, I broke down the big `string.Join` of complete `List` into element by elment joining.

Comment: string.Join() Function doesn't change the order of List element internally.

Comment: And that's why I posted this question along with the output to explain the issue!!

Comment: Problem is somewhere else. If 5th line is the output in your post how it starts with a comma ??

Comment: Exactly!  `string.Join` is scrambling the result. That's why I asked for a suggestion on a `Format` for string manipulation. It's not somewhere else, it's in the `string.Join`'s underline configuration that may depend on `locale` specific `Format`s.